# Help understanding Garling's proof that closed and bounded is equivalent to compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm self-studying real analysis using A course in mathematical analysis by Garling

In the proof that, in $\Bbb{R}$, compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ closed and bounded I don't understand how they deduce that  $V_n = \{x \in \Bbb{R} : |x-a| \gt \frac{1}{n} \}$ covers the arbitrary compact set B if $a \not\in B$

I don't believe any more of the proof is relevant to this but to this point they have proven compactness $\Rightarrow$ boundedness and that closed and bounded $\Rightarrow$ compactness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in B$ then $|x-a|\ne 0$ and so there is a positive integer $n$ such that $|x-a|>\frac{1}{n}.$

Therefore $x\in V_n.$

Comment: Ah so every x is in some $V_n$ so the union of all the $V_n$ includes all $x \in B$. I was just considering each $V_n$ on its own

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use the definition of compactness that says that every open cover of a compact set has a finite subcover.

Assume the condition doesn't hold. What then? Well, you can come up with at least one sequence of real numbers contained in the compact set that converge monotonically towards a. You know this because $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $x\in B$ such that $|x-a|<1/n$ by assumption.

Well, now that you have this sequence, you can come up with an open cover of B that doesn't have a finite subcover. So, say our sequence approaches a from below. Then take the open set $(-\infty,a_1)$ where $a_1$ is the first value in our sequence. Then, for the rest of the points in B between $(a_1,a)$ you can cover these with the the set containing all intervals $(a_{i-1},a_{i+1})$.

We know that this covers B completely between $a_1$ and a because $a_i$ converges to a and the intervals contain all $a_i$ and all points between them. We also know that there is no finite subcover since that would mean that there is some M for which $a_M$ is not in the subcover, but it is in B. But that's a contradiction because B is compact.